# how can i fix the error ? stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

Tags: arduino-mega, bootloader

I bought [this Chinese Arduino Mega 2560 16AU](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/MEGA-2560-R3-ATmega2560-R3-AVR-USB-board-Free-USB-Cable-for-Arduino-2560-MEGA2560/32437126167.html).

This was the first time to deal with Arduino boards. When I try to upload a sketch I always get this error:

`stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer`

I successfully burnt a bootloader to it using an Arduino uno,
but the same error is there.

Finally I discovered the the loop test is not working, and only the LX LED flashes once  when I enter a letter in the serial monitor.

Answer (score 1):

It's our old friend the CH340G again, isn't it?

You've been sold a dud, I'm afraid. The USB chip used there is dead. It happens a lot with those cheap Chinese boards. You should still be able to use the board with an external FTDI adapter by wiring it in to TX->RX, RX->TX and DTR->RESET (via a 100nF capacitor) with power and ground connected of course.

There is also a slim chance that the CH340G may interfere with the TX/RX pins, in which case you may need to remove it. Simply cutting the pins on it with an xacto knife then removing the stumps with a soldering iron and tweezers would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If You Downloaded the driver it should be fine!

https://github.com/jimaobian/CH34x_Install_V1.3